# How to remove a function programmatically in a WordPress RSS feed?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to remove the `the_guid()` function that appears in feed-rss2.php. I've tried `remove_action('rss2_item', 'the_guid')` or `remove_filter` but nothing happens. I’ve also tried different hooks like `the_content_rss`...

The function appears on line 43 of [feed-rss2.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php), enclosed by `<item></item>`.

**Update**

With `echo current_filter()`, I found that the hook is `do_feed_rss2`. But I still can't remove the function.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the whole `GUID` node or just the function and replace the value with your own version?

Comment: Just replace the function with mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the output of that function via a filter.

```
add_filter('get_the_guid','my_get_the_guid');
function my_get_the_guid($guid) {
    $my_guid = 'foo';
    return $my_guid;
}
```

Using that you can override the GUID output with anything you want. You can't delete the node in the RSS output, but you can control its content. If you want to delete the node all together you could create your own XML template, keep it on your theme, and then use the template_redirect action to force load your template instead of the default.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Feed Wrangler plugin works great for customizing feeds:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-wrangler/

Basically, install the plugin, denote a feed with a slug (ex: **no-guid**), then add a **feed-no-guid.php** file to your theme. You can use the default feed files in `wp-includes/` as a base and delete or add whatever items you want. That way, you get complete control of the feed and a clear upgrade path in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line 40 in /wp-includes/feed-rss2.php:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
```

Try deleting that and see what happens; it's the only reference to the_guid in the file

Comment: Deleting is fine. I want to remove it automatically (and replace it with something else) via a plugin or functions.php, so I don't have to manually change it after every WordPress upgrade.